# How to add React to an already built website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I already have a built website with Express and I wanted to use React just in some pages. How is the best way to add it having all the resources that I have using the create-react-app?

I know I can add each script to the HTML file, but that is kind of error prone and laborious. I just wanted to be able to do all the import and manage the files the same way I do with an application using create-react-app.

Comment: You can't do that easily, a CRA SPA is completely different to a server-rendered Express app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to use React in some already existing pages, I would suggest you to go through importing the script as React documentation talks about [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html). It gives you a nice and short example on how to do add react components to existing html pages. You only need to import the react and react-dom dependencies once in your html entry-point (probably index.html), then in each page you only import the required components.

The other alternative is to follow the idea [in this guide](https://daveceddia.com/create-react-app-express-backend/), to build the app using both create-react-app and express. You would want to move all the html code into React components and handle everything from React, and you will be able to manage all the project structure like you wish. But I believe this is more error prone and a lot of effort, if you only want to add React to build some componentes in just some pages.